# How do I get detailed message from a DOM error event

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-component, html-imports

I'm trying to understand Chrome's implementation of html import such as

```
 <link id="test_component" rel="import" href="http://localhost:8888/fail.html" onerror="handler(event)">
```

However the error event doesn't really convey much useful message as specified in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/error) . I wonder if there's any way I can get more out of the error event such as reason of failure and HTTP status code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error event handler is triggered, you can *replay* the request by using `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` in order to get more information about the failure.

```
function handler(event) 
{
    fetch(event.target.href)
        .then( resp => console.info(resp.status) )
        .catch( err => console.log(err) )
}
```

Comment: Very interesting solution. On server side we'd expect to see the exact same request happened twice. There shouldn't be any significant downsides as all such requests shall be GETs, but kinda funny to see things appear as twins XD